# Jquery, hide img onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

I want an image to be hidden when page just loaded. I can call `$('#imgName').show()` to show the image.

However, I had

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#imgName").hide();
});
```

But the image still flashes right at the start.

How do you get rid of this flashing effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because javascripts are loaded after html, the nearest possible solution is to use css

```
img#imgName{display:none}
```

Comment: Is there a way to get rid of the flash but display the image for people without JS enabled?

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS 'display: none;' to make it not visible on load.

Comment: And with JQuery you can change the CSS attribute when some event happens.

Comment: Very true; however, doing that once the document has loaded will keep the flicker. Definitely a good thing to remember though.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear enough, indeed you are right. I meant to say, Nik's answer is correct and after the page has loaded you can change the style by updating the CSS property with a javascript event, like a button click or whatever makes sense. The reason you see the flicker is that JQuery is executed AFTER the entire document has been rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Try using CSS to initially hide the image. The Javascript will load after the CSS, generally -- ergo, the initial flash.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the image with it hidden using css.

```
display:none;
```